# HttpPostedfileBase is null using jQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have problem with uploading file In Asp.net Mvc. First of all I should use Ajax to pass the upload file value.

In javascript I have model that I fill it, When I check it with debugger is correctly fill the object, but when I send this model to server (Controller )

The httpPostedfileBase value is Always null.

I search it on google, in some post I saw that I cant use file uploader with Ajax, but in other I saw that I can.

But I can not fix my Code.

There is my Javascript Code.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#btnUploadFile').on('click', function () {
   var data= new FormData();

    debugger;
    var files = $("#fileUpload").get(0).files;

    if (files.length > 0) {
        data.append("UploadedImage", files[0]);
    }
    var ResturantSharingViewModel =
   {
       Type: $("#SharingTargetType").val(),
       SharingTitle: $("#SharingTitle").val(),
       content: $("#Content").val(),
       ItemId : $("#ItemId").val(),
       Photos: files[0]
   };
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: '<%= Url.Action("SaveOneDatabase")%>',
        data: JSON.stringify(ResturantSharingViewModel),
          success: function (result) {
              var rs = result;
          },
          error: function () {
              alert("Error loading data! Please try again.");
          }
      });
```

My Controller `public virtual bool SaveOneDatabase(ResturantSharingViewModel result)`

My ResturantSharingViewModel  View Model

```
 public class ResturantSharingViewModel
{
    public Guid SharingPremiumHistoryID { get; set; }
    public string SharingTitle { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public DateTime AddedDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsSubmit { get; set; }
    public DateTime SubmitedDate { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SharingTypes { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SharingTargetType { get; set; }
    public short Type { get; set; }
    public Guid ItemId { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase[] Photos { get; set; }
}
```

My Html Elements

```
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <article>
    <%--<% =Html.BeginForm("Add","PremiumSharing") %>--%>
   <hgroup class="radiogroup">
    <h1>ارسال خبر</h1>
    <%= Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SharingPremiumHistoryID) %>
    <%= Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ItemId) %>
    <div class="group">
        <span> ارسال به </span>
        <%= Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SharingTargetType, Model.SharingTypes) %>
    </div>
</hgroup>
<div class="newseditor">
    <div class="input-form">
        <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.SharingTitle, "عنوان خبر") %>
        <%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SharingTitle) %>
    </div>

    <div class="input-form">
        <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.Content, "متن خبر") %>
        <%= Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Content) %>
    </div>
    <div><input id="fileUpload" type="file" />

    </div>
    <% if (ViewBag.IsInEditMode != null && !(bool)ViewBag.IsInEditMode)
       {%>
    <div class="input-form">
        <%= Html.CheckBox("SendToInTheCity") %> ارسال در بخش «در شهر» فیدیلیو
    </div>
    <%} %>

    <div class="input-submit">
        <button name="post" id="btnUploadFile"  onclick="uploadFile()" >ارسال خبر</button>
    </div>
    <br />
</div>
```

Comment: What do you see if you add "HttpPostedFileBase file" as input parameter in your controller?

Comment: What You Mean sir , Can you give me example ?

Comment: Saw now in your title you use HttpPostedFileBased. Sorry.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First, it's possible to upload with Ajax, the important thing is you need to set `<form enctype="multipart/form-data"></form>` on you form to tell it your form has an file upload input. Then you need to accept `HttpPostedFileBase` as an input parameter in your controller action.

Try this. Example of jquery upload code. (Taken mostly from [How can I upload files asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously))

```
function uploadFile(uploadId) {
    var formData = new FormData($('form')[0]);

    $.ajax({
        url: '<%= Url.Action("SaveOneDatabase")%>',
        type: 'Post',
        beforeSend: function(){},
        success: function(result){

        },
        xhr: function() {  // Custom XMLHttpRequest
        var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            if(myXhr.upload) { // Check if upload property exists
                // Progress code if you want
            }
            return myXhr;
        },
        error: function(){},
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
}
```

HTML Form needs this attribute. See this post why you need it -> [What does enctype='multipart/form-data' mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean)

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

C#

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveOneDatabase(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
}
```

Comment: Could you show what your form-element and input type file element looks like?

Comment: @salar I changed the code a bit, what browser are you using?

Comment: i use firefox Developer edition , it think it s not related to browsers

Comment: @salar If you'd used IE 9 and below it would not have worked. This should work though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70424/discussion-between-andreas-and-salar).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70427/discussion-between-andreas-and-salar).

Comment: how to set file control in formdata without using index i.e. $('form')[0] I don't want to use index. Can I use direct id of that control and set it?

Comment: @3rules You'd have to have an ID on your `<form>` tag, get that object into a variable, and then pass that variable in, but it should be the same thing. Ex. `<form id="myForm">...</form>` then `var form1 = $(#myForm); var formData = new FormData(form1);`

Answer (score 7):

I have modified @a moradi's answer.

**JS:**

```
//FormData:
//Consider it a normal form but with "multipart/form-data" encoding type.
//Inside it works same as XMLHttpRequest.send() method.    
var model = new FormData();
model.append("File", $('#file')[0].files[0]);
model.append("Name", "Name");
$.ajax({ 
        url: someUrl,
        type: "POST",
        data: model,
        //contentType: 
        //Sets the ContentType in header.
        //The default contentType is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8". But this will prevent us sending AntiForgeryToken to service/controller.
        //To prevent this contentType is set to false.
        contentType: false,
        //processData:
        //To prevent data getting converted to string format, 'processData' option is set to false.
        processData: false,
        success = function (m) {...}
        error = function (m) {...}
    });
```

**View Model:**

```
public class PhotoAlbumViewModel {
    public  string Name { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public JsonResult AddPhoto(PhotoAlbumViewModel model) {
    ...
}
```

**Refrence:**

Reffer following links for details: [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) , [JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) , [ContentType](https://nozzlegear.com/blog/send-and-validate-an-asp-net-antiforgerytoken-as-a-request-header)

Comment: Works like a charm

Comment: Can I do this without View Model?

Answer (score 5):

**View:**

```
<script/>
var add_photo_url = "@Url.Action("AddPhoto", "Gallery")"; 
    var model = new FormData();    
    var i=0;//selected file index 
    model.append("File", files[i]);
    model.append("Name", "test");
    $.ajax({// and other parameter is set here 
        url: add_photo_url,
            type: "POST",
            data: model,
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false

        })
        .always(function (result) { 
        });
</script>
```

**View Model:**

```
public class PhotoAlbumViewModel {
    public  string Name { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public JsonResult AddPhoto(PhotoAlbumViewModel model) {
    // var result =...
    // and set your result; 
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation for your code. Code-only answers are discouraged.

Comment: Can I do this without a ViewModel ?

Comment: is this method working?  `public JsonResult AddPhoto(string Name,HttpPostedFileBase File)`