# Httppostedfilebase always returns null when posted with jquery ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I am developing an mvc application and want to upload file into server.
At the controller when event fires the fileupload is null.And also the model.fileupload has the path.
Actually am submitting my form using ajax post method.

cshtml code....

```
<form id="frmRegistrationDetails" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <label>Upload File</label><input type="file" id="fileupload"  name="fileupload" />
         </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</form>
```

controller code

```
 [HttpPost]
 public JsonResult SaveDetails(reg_up_mvc model,HttpPostedFileBase fileupload)
  {
  try
  {
    detailsRegistration registrationContext = new detailsRegistration();
    reg_up_mvc registrationDetails = new reg_up_mvc();
    registrationDetails.full_name = model.full_name;
    registrationDetails.fileupload = model.fileupload;
if (model.fileupload != null)
{
string sPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFilesFromRegistration"), fileupload.FileName);
fileupload.SaveAs(sPath);
registrationDetails.fileupload = sPath;
}
```

jquery

```
var data = {
        model: {
                fileupload: $('#fileupload').val()
               }
    };
     $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        url: "/Controller/ActionName",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        success: function (response) {
                           alert("successful")
                           }
         });
```

Comment: Please `console.log` the `JSON.stringify(data),` and tell us what it is.

Comment: model:fileupload:"C\fakepath\download.jpg".forgot to add id to <input type=file id="fileupload" name="fileupload"/>

Comment: had tried it by making it same but helpless.so just changed its name field and tried to retrive value by name element.but still hopeless

Comment: `model:fileupload:"C\fakepath\download.jpg"` That doesn't look like JSON. You are sure it was **exactly** that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HttpPostedfileBase is null using jQuery Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28373894/httppostedfilebase-is-null-using-jquery-ajax)

Comment: `{"model":{"full_name":"sdfdsf","emailid":"sdfdsf","password":"sdfdsfs","state_res":"1","district":"1","gender":"Male","fileupload":"C:\\fakepath\\download-hill.jfif","language":"english"}}`

Comment: `,"fileupload":"C:\\fakepath\\download-hill.jfif"` That isn't the file **contents**. That is the **path** to the file. The server can't do anything useful with that.

Answer (score 0):

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28373894/httppostedfilebase-is-null-using-jquery-ajax?noredirect=1&lq=1
```

already answered in this oneplease check